# Unable to run sample Meteor app on device

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, meteor

I downloaded the sample Meteor application, simple-todos, and after running `meteor run ios-device`, I am receiving this error:

[image]

Anyone have an idea on how to troubleshoot this? I followed all of the steps on [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-run-your-app-on-an-iOS-device) page, but it still does not work.

Comment: Make sure you do 'meteor install-sdk ios' as well as 'meteor add-platform ios' then try running it again

Comment: I tried that already. I still receive that error.

Comment: Have you tried just 'meteor run ios'?